# How to use load control from another page in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file called `"psstep2tabstrip.ascx.cs"` where defines public partial class:

```
public partial  class PSStep2Display :Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Web.UI.Components.WMCCMControl
```

in this file I can call:

```
PSStep2Display control = (PSStep2Display) LoadControl("~/WMCCM/PartnerSearch/PSStep2Display.ascx");
```

Now in my file
`companies.ascx.cs` I make the same call:

```
PSStep2Display control = (PSStep2Display) LoadControl("~/WMCCM/PartnerSearch/PSStep2Display.ascx");
```

But it cannot recognize

```
 PSStep2Display
```

I already tried to include the header of `"psstep2tabstrip.ascx"` to the header of `"companies.ascx"`:

```
   <%@ Reference Control="~/wmccm/partnersearch/psstep2display.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="iewc" Namespace="Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Control Language="c#" Inherits="Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Web.UI.PartnerSearch.PSStep2TabStrip" Codebehind="PSStep2TabStrip.ascx.cs" %>
```

But it still cannot recognize. How could I correct this error here ?

Comment: Is you PSStep2Display class defined inside the psstep2tabstrip class as a nested class?

Comment: It is defined as I mentioned above. Inside it also have many other class defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the name space of `PSStep2Display` control as a **using** directive if you'd like to use the control like

```
PSStep2Display control = (PSStep2Display) LoadControl("~/WMCCM/PartnerSearch/PSStep2Display.ascx");
```

Instead of that use it like this

```
Control control = LoadControl("~/WMCCM/PartnerSearch/PSStep2Display.ascx");
```

Comment: I tried that but if I use that method, it will not able to recognize the other definition under PSStep2Display, eg. control.Category = cat; control.urlSuffix = this._urlSuffix; control.frameworkId

Comment: What do you mean by "must use the name space of PSStep2Display control as a using directive ", how to write it, can u give an example ?

Comment: I mean you should use the name space surrounding the class PSStep2Display as a using directive in companies.ascx.cs file. E.g. if the name space of PSStep2Display is MyNameSpace then you must use "using MyNameSpace;" on top of the companies.ascx.cs file.

Comment: Looks like putting the namespace is the right thing, but is it the right way to just use namespace in any file like that ? As I put using ThatNameSpace, it can now recognize PSStep2Display, but when I build the project, there are many error, eg. the name 'grouping1' does not exist in the current context, etc. looks like it not link to the file where all that names are defined...?

Comment: Yes that's the correct way. You have a different issue now. If "grouping1" is defined in "PSStep2Display" you should make it public to be visible in other controls.

Comment: You are right, that is caused by another thing. Thanks for the suggestion about Using NameSpace. That is exactly the answer I am looking for !

Answer (score 1):

1. To make it visible use [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664766(v=vs.71).aspx).
2. If PSStep2Display is [nested class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173120.aspx) you should reference it like ContainerClass.NestedClass.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found the solution and accepted other answer about using namespace!